# Long In Review Time

Tags: app-store-connect

I've submitted an app to iTunes Connect via Xcode and I got an email from iTunes Connect which informs me about "Waiting For Review" situation at 4th of September. After waiting in the queue, on 9th of September, I got another email which notifies me that my app's status changed to In Review. Unfortunately, six calendar days later, my app's status is still "In Review". Therefore, I submitted a contact us form of iTunes Connect. They've sent a reply to me that my app is in still review, they'll inform me... etc. Up to now, I don't have any requests from Apple, emails about my app. Is it normal or not and what do I need to do?(My app contains Non-Consumable in-App purchase)

Comment: Could you edit in details about the app. It is a web view skin, or some framework with light customization or is it a heavy swift/obj c centric cocoa app? How many apps like this do you have on the store already? Is this the first time this app is under review?

Answer (score 1):

A month for a tricky review is possible. I've seen much longer.

Add the iOS 9 release crunch and you could be waiting 6 or more weeks. The only reason I would call would be if I was willing to cut content and remove a potentially troubling aspect of the app to smooth review.

Even then, it really depends upon context. Whether the app is under first review or this is a patch update. IAP can delay things but it really depends on how your app was built.

Comment: My app just contains a list and a function that choses strings from array randomly. I've used IAP to add more strings to array. It looks simple from here. :)

Comment: @twigofa cool. Like a magic eight ball novelty app? That's going to be a hard sell in a crowded market, but I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give Apple a **call** and ask them what gives. They may not be of any help, but at least you could bring your issue to their attention.

Comment: I disagree. In review means a human took the app off the queue and has started work on it. Review is better than rejection and if there's any chance the reviewer wants to give the app the benefit of the doubt, a call would be pointless since the OP already asked for them to double check the status. I might call after three weeks of no contact but being overly needy could work against your app.